# Left Join on Three tables not giving expected output

Tags: ms-access, join, left-join

I have three tables, purchase, purchase_item, and customer. Iam trying to use left join on these tables. But, iam not getting the expected result in MS Access.

the query is:
SELECT *
FROM (CUSTOMER
left JOIN purchase ON CUSTOMER.CustomerID = PURCHASE.CustomerID) left join purchase_item on purchase_item.InvoiceNumber = purchase.InvoiceNumber;

Getting output as :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMJfs.png

I have double-checked all the tables. All the tables have matching data, but still purchase_item data is not getting populated when trying to view all the data. Please help me to find where Iam going wrong.

PURCHASE table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnPT7.png

PURCHASE_ITEM table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbM2d.png

CUSTOMER table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqZ9q.png

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]
Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Please in code questions give a [mre].

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation.

Comment: You have not acted per my comments. PS Please look at the formatted version of your post before you publish. See edit help re code blocks & line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

First, try correcting the ON order:

...LEFT JOIN purchase_item ON *purchase.InvoiceNumber = purchase_item.InvoiceNumber*

It is good practice to use the form: A JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID

If this doesn't work, answer back, and we can look at other things to try.